# How do some websites avoid responding to https requests made from inside node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

**Environment:** Node.js, Express

**Question:** I was experimenting in Express and nearly every website responds to an https request.  However I found one site that didn't respond at all.  How is this possible when it is viewable in Chrome?  I assume many sites can do this.

**Example:** In the example below I check to see if 2 different sites are active by making https requests.  Both sites are available in Chrome.  websiteOne responds as nearly all sites do with a response.  websiteTwo sends back nothing.  How do they do this?  Is there another efficient way inside Node to see if a site is currently active?

```
"use strict";

// Express is installed
const https = require('https');

let websiteOne = 'https://www.cat.com';
let websiteTwo = 'https://www.dog.com';

https.get(websiteOne, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
});

https.get(websiteTwo, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
});
```

Comment: It's possible for a server to look for the typical headers (user-agent, accepts, etc...) that would accompany a browser and refuse to serve a request that doesn't look like it's coming from a known browser.  This isn't particularly secure as one can emulate all the same headers that come from a browser, but it's possible some sites still do it.  If you show us the links to the ACTUAL sites that exhibit this, we could probably figure it out.  Without any specific sites to look at, all we can do is make theoretical guesses.

Comment: Very interesting.  It's `https://www.dog.com`

Comment: I'd just like to add that `https` is a native node-module and not related to express. (And if you have a three-letter actual word .com, it makes sense you'd want to filter out some less relevant requests... ) I also tested to just add a user agent, and that is still not enough for dog.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webservers don't necessarily have to send you a response. If your request is deemed invalid by the webserver (eg: incorrect headers, insufficient parameters etc), it can either skip that request or respond with an error code. You should try to ping the server to check for end-to-end connection without actually sending a request to the server. Try *npm install ping*

Comment: I don't know why a ping would be a solution here.  A server can be up and running for https requests and not respond to ping.  ping is an extra service that the server decides if they want to run or not.  Some do, some do not.  Besides, I thought the real question here was how to get an actual response from `https://www.dog.com`?